# How to sessionize actions using spark?

Tags: python, pyspark

import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

I'm using AWS glue to sessionize actions, which looks like this:

```
#actions are grouped by SessionId
{"ItemViewed": 0, "DisheartedItem": 0, "PageChanged": 1, "Source": "bing", "SessionId": 85151275, "ActionCounter": 1, "LoadedItems": 0, "Action": "pagechange", "AddedFilter": 0, "ItemAddedToCart": 0, "InstanceId": "i-0fbf940e44eb8b479", "RemovedFilter": 0, "HeartedItem": 0, "Date": "2020-01-27 19:45:25"}
```

My script is simple, it just converts the dynamic frame to data frame and gets certain variables then converts back.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database_name", table_name = "raw_actions", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

#convert to dataframe
df = datasource0.toDF()

#group by SessionId
w = Window.partitionBy('SessionId')


grouped = df.select(
    'SessionId', 
    f.first('InstanceId').over(w).alias('InstanceId'),
    f.first('Source').over(w).alias('Source'),
    f.count('SessionId').over(w).alias('Actions'),
    #etc...
).dropDuplicates()

#convert back to dynamicframe
dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(grouped, glueContext, 'dynamicframe')
```

But I keep getting this error, I'm not sure why

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`SessionId`' given input columns: [];;\n'Project [first('SessionId, false) windowspecdefinition('SessionId, unspecifiedframe$()) AS SessionId#1, first('InstanceId, false) windowspecdefinition('SessionId, unspecifiedframe$()) AS InstanceId#3, first('Source, false) windowspecdefinition('SessionId, unspecifiedframe$()) AS Source#5]\n+- LogicalRDD false\n"
```

I have also tried using :

```
grouped = df.select(
    df['SessionId'], 
    f.first('InstanceId').over(w).alias('InstanceId'),
    f.first('Source').over(w).alias('Source'),
    f.count('SessionId').over(w).alias('Actions'),
    #etc...
).dropDuplicates()
```

and I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve column name "SessionId" among ();'
```

Comment: have you tried to replace 'SessionId' with col df['SessionId'] in your select?

Comment: yes I just tried and I get a different error(edited question with error)

Comment: can you confirm if your dataframe has some data present by .show() or .count() ? and also see the column names by printSchema?